React Native Image Picker Not Working : Task :react-native-image-picker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
I have been trying to integrate react-native-image-picker in my React Native Android app, but I am facing issues after following the setup instructions. The app doesn't load the image picker correctly,
after i run :
cd android
./gradlew clean
cd ..
npx react-native run-androidpe here

i get that error :

Task :react-native-image-picker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
Image for error i get : 
Below are the steps I've followed and things I have tried.
Steps I Followed:

Installed react-native-image-picker:
npm install react-native-image-picker


Linked the library manually in MainApplication.java:

I ensured to manually add the ImagePickerPackage inside the getPackages() method:
import com.imagepicker.ImagePickerPackage;
@Override
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
    packages.add(new ImagePickerPackage());
    return packages;
}




Updated react-native-image-picker to the latest version:
I ran:
npm install react-native-image-picker@latest




Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! Is there something specific I might be missing? can you help me troubleshoot the steps in my configuration? Thank you in advance!

You'll need to include the full error so we can tell exactly what's wrong. Check about the Task :react-native-image-picker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED line, there should be a more specific error message there

You can removed the ^ to retain the at 7.1.2 version.
React Native: ^0.72.15
React: 18.2.0

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
